# How can I give server access to my Developer?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am have AWS EC2 Server with my App Backend and Database there.

My new developer needs to upload few things in the Database and update Backend code but I don't want to give him the PEM.

He needs to SSH

Whats the best possible way to do it? I was thinking of creating an IAM User for him - but I only want him to give SSH Access, so permission would that be? I could only find a general full permission EC2 which would also give him permission to edit the Security Group and things like that.

I do trust him well, but I just don't want to give him full access in general.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Why not allow your developer to connect using [session manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with.html).

If you use this he can access the environment either in his browser or via the AWS CLI.

He should be able to mimic a regular session but without having the key, then when he's done you remove the permissions of the server. You can also enable logging to check the history of his sessions actions.

If you want to update code you should at some point take a look at using [code deploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/) to have the code automatically rolled out without even accessing the server.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Chris! I will definitely have a look at code deploy.. but for now, the best solution is to create an IAM user with Session Manager permission (which one is that exactly only to start a session) and what other permission he needs?

Comment: Because Session Manager is only to record what he is doing, as fas as I understood?

Comment: No it also allows him to connect to the instance, the permissions should all be covered in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started.html

Comment: I see.. is there no easier way to allow him SSH access and I added him to the security group. 

For example now, I have shared my DB Configuration and added his IP temporarily in the Security Group, so once he is done with the work I will simply remove his IP and will no longer able to access my DB. 

is there a similar way to do the same but for the server in order for him to upload the files/do some testing?

Comment: You should create him a temporary SSH user with a key and then remove it once he's done but you would be entirely responsible for that :). Even if you remove his IP, also remove the account once its no longer needed

Comment: Even if you remove his IP, also remove the account once its no longer needed --> didn't get the part 'even if you remove his IP'? 

So even if I remove his IP, he would be able to log in?

Comment: Not through SSH from that IP, but its always worth removing any unused "backdoors" to your server from a security point of view.

Comment: You should add a new user in Linux and have him login to that. Using `ec2-user` is dangerous because it includes `sudo` access. See: [Add New User Accounts with SSH Access to an Amazon EC2 Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I see - but I all my backdoors would be closed again, once I removed his IP again? 
John Rotentstein: So you are not suggesting to use session manager?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein So you are not suggesting to use session manager?

Comment: @Sammuel this will always be upto your approach, both work. I believe John was expanding on the comments to say if you grant SSH access (rather than sessions manager) then you should create a specific user for them, not giving them access to the default user of the OS as this user has elevated privileges.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Hmm, now I am confused..So there are 2 options right: create an IAM user, add his IP to the security group and give me session manager access OR I can create a new linux user for my instance, so he would not be working through the main linux username, but another and on a "copy" then also of my actual server?